# Cannot reload AVD list: Premature end of file. after cancelled android-tv SDK install

Tags: android, android-sdk-2.3

I tried to update my android TV SDK, but ran out of memory and had to cancel the install.  When I tried to run an app later, I got this error:

> Cannot reload AVD list: Premature end of file. Error parsing /home/USERNAME/.AndroidStudio1.4/sdk/system-images/android-23/android-tv/armeabi-v7a/devices.xml Premature end of file. Error parsing

The `devices.xml` file was empty.  There's the problem!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To solve this, first I cleared up some memory on my computer and completed the update.  I still got the error.  I wasn't really using the SDK so I uninstalled it and restarted Android Studio.  Still got the error.

Finally, I deleted the whole `/home/USERNAME/.AndroidStudio1.4/sdk/system-images/android-23/android-tv/` folder.  The error finally went away.  If you're actually using the SDK, you can always install it again with the SDK manager.